# How is the value of dx and dy 256 in tour.golang.org/moretypes/18?

Tags: go, default-value

I've been learning golang using tour.golang.org.

In the following code, when I print the value of dx and dy which are both of type integer, the value comes out to be 256.

```
package main

import ("golang.org/x/tour/pic"
        "fmt"
        )

func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    fmt.Printf("%T\n",dx)
    fmt.Println(dx)
    
    ret := make([][]uint8, dy)
    for i := range(ret){
        ret[i] = make([]uint8, dx)
    }
    return ret
}

func main() {
    pic.Show(Pic)
}
```

How does the golang compiler know the value of those two integers declared in the function Pic?

Comment: The compiler knows nothing about dx. This are plain values from package pic.

Comment: the code lacks formatting.

Comment: https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/tour/+/refs/tags/v0.1.0:pic/pic.go;l=27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `main`, you're calling [`pic.Show`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tour/pic#Show) with your function, `Pic`. Looking at the [source code](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/tour/+/refs/tags/v0.1.0:pic/pic.go;l=27) for `pic.Show`, it calls the function it's given with 256 for each dimension.